# how to receive / update data when it changes (Firebase) in swift

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data stored on firebase and when somebody adds to my data, through my app I want to receive and update my data. I looked at the google docs and it said to something like this...

```
 databaseRef.child("Leaderboard").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childChanged, with: {
        snapshot in 

let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
// put data into variables
let playerName = value?["playerName"] as! String?


 }
```

But for some reason it returns nil, I know I have my hierarchy right. Why is it returning nil?

Comment: What exactly is returning nil? Also, maybe do post some of your database structure just so we can verify thet it's right.

Comment: When I print `value?["playerName"]` it returns nil.

Comment: And what happens when you print snapshot.value?

Comment: It prints everything fine, I also have a value["playerScore"] in my code and it prints both items fine.

Comment: Can we see the output of print(snapshot.value)?

Answer (score 1):

```
let playerName: String = value!["playerName"] as? String
```